# How do I correct the path for pip?

Tags: python, path, pip

I'm trying to get pip to point to a different install rather than the default.  It is currently pointing to /usr/bin/pip, but I want it to point to /usr/local/bin/pip.  I believe I have the path set correctly and everything else points to the correct location.

What's the best way to resolve this?

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin

# which python
/usr/local/bin/python

# which easy_install
/usr/local/bin/easy_install

# which pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/pip` exist and is it executable for your user?

Comment: What does `which -a pip` output?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/pip does exist for users.

# which -a pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

Answer (score 8):

Using 'alias' is another possible option. Just put it into the relevant shell configuration file (for execution each time your shell is executed).

```
$ alias pip='/usr/bin/pip'
$ alias pip
alias pip='/usr/bin/pip'
$ alias pip='/usr/local/bin/pip'
$ alias pip
alias pip='/usr/local/bin/pip'
$ pip
bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you have both `pip` installed via `easy_install` and OS package manager. If you want to use only one, just remove another one.

In your case, you want `pip` from `easy_install`, so just removing which one from OS package manager.

With `Debian/Ubuntu`:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
```

With `Redhat/Centos/Fedora`:

```
sudo yum remove python-pip
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify PATH to local `pip` in `~/.bash_profile` file.
Supposed that you you would like to use `pip` from `/usr/local/bin/pip`,
you can add `export PATH=$HOME/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to the file. 
This will add the desired PATH to existing PATH (`$PATH`).

Then, `source ~/.bash_profile` to update the PATH.

Check `pip`path again by typing `which pip`.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody mentioned this here but a symlink would do the trick as well. In my case since /usr/bin is the default path for every program, just make the pip symlink point to the correct pip executable.

Comment: But in my case I already have a pip executable in `/usr/bin`, so can I just delete it and replace with simlink?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your ~/.bashrc file to include the path to your preferred pip installation.
E.g.

```
alias pip='/usr/bin/pip'
```

Then source your .bashrc file for it to come into action.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Check:
    which pip

/usr/bin/pip